# String spaces issue in Flutter Text widget

Tags: flutter, text

I am trying to create a Text widget from my string with spaces.
But in the app my text is not aligned at right like in text.

Any idea how to solve it? Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       title: 'Flutter Text Demo',
       home: MyHomePage(),
     );
   }
 }

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Text(
        '''
 04.03.2021                      11:02:56
 Trm-Id:                         23690130
 AID:                      A0000000032020
 Trx Seq-Nr:                         5429
 Trx Ref. Nr:                 58894675511
        ''',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: code example and result]

Comment: Please don't use text like this. Each device will have its own dimensions and hence the text will look different on each device. To get what you need use a combination of rows and/ or columns. Let me know if you need help with the code

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that space in your editor has a certain pixel value, but in your emulator it is different, that is why it is looking different.
To solve this problem you need to divide the screen into certain ratios and in those ratios, you could define your widgets.

To divide your screen you need a use a widget, known as `Expanded`. This widget uses the parameter `flex`, which takes integer values in it to divide the screen in a ratio. For example, `flex: 1` would mean 1/10 of the height/width.

Your problem could be solved like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Text Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Text("Trm-Id")
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text(":")
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: Text("23690130")
              )
            ]
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Text("AID")
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text(":")
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: Text("A0000000032020")
              )
            ]
          ),
          //And so on
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Here is you code: [image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use Column and Row for alignment:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       title: 'Flutter Text Demo',
       home: MyHomePage(),
     );
   }
 }

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Column(children:[
        Row(children:[
          Text('04.03.2021'),
          Spacer(),
          Text('11:02:56'),
            ],
          ),
        Row(children:[
          Text('04.03.2021'),
          Spacer(),
          Text('11:02:56'),
            ],
          ),
        Row(children:[
          Text('04.03.2021'),
          Spacer(),
          Text('11:02:56'),
            ],
          ),
        Row(children:[
          Text('04.03.2021'),
          Spacer(),
          Text('11:02:56'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, this dynamic text i will get from server and shouldn't modify it))

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, consider using the [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) widget, which can created a very uniform look and is especially useful for larger tables.